# Sqlite decimal value not working

Tags: sqlite

I am usuing SQLite. I want to select only the 2 digits of decimal value.

that means if the input is 99.013,then the answer will be 99.01.

I used getBigDecimal("Data",2)... but it giving an error that sqlite does not support getBigDecimal.

Please give some idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try [round()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) instead.

```
round(data, 2)
```

Be cautious that round(99.013, 2) is 99.01 but round(99.015, 2) is 99.02. By `getBigDecimal` I guess you are using JDBC. Maybe it would be easier to do this kind of data handling in Java rather than by SQLite.